# Passing to curly brackets with value to XContainer.Descendants() does what?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linux-containers

I don't see an explanation for using curly brackets in:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx

I noticed in an exam:
`feed.Descendants("{urn:CFI}Flight").Concat(feed.Descendants(Flight));`

The xml it's referring to was:

```
<AirlineFeed>
 <Flight xmlns:"urn:cfi" name:"AS515">
  <Seats>123</Seats>
 </Flight>

 <Flightname:"UN24">
  <Seats>96</Seats>
 </Flight>
</AirLineFeed>
```

What does the curly bracket do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page you linked: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx

The method `XContainer.Descendants()` takes a paramater `XName` of type `System.Xml.Linq.XName`.

If you look at the msdn page for `System.Xml.Linq.XName`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname(v=vs.110).aspx

You can see from **Remarks**:

> XML names include a namespace and a local name. A fully qualified name
>   is the combination of the namespace and local name.

and from **Using Expanded Names**

> You can also create an XName from a expanded XML name in the form {namespace}localname

Comment: so from the code, am I effectively requesting all Flight elements that have an xmlns with a value of "urn:cfi"?

Comment: The namespace defined by `xmlns` in your example is `urn:cfi`. You can see from the `XContainer.Descendants()` documentation the method returns an `IEnumerable` which contains the `concat()` method that concatenates two sequences see: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx). Since this was an exam question I'm trying to avoid simply providing the output of the function calls so you can get to the answer yourself.

Comment: That is what the first call is doing, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, I wasn't sure if it was actually just placing in what was in quotations, or functionally using it, however upon running the code in VS if I put in the curly brackets a xmlns that doesn't exist the console writes nothing (used the examples from the links), so it is seeking what I request.